# Does grails 3.0.9 use Gpars or not?

Tags: grails, groovy, gpars

I am reading this: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/async.html 
and I am trying to understand if the latest Grails is using Gpars by default.

It says this:

*The excellent GPars project features a whole range of different APIs for asynchronous programming techniques including actors, promises, STM and data flow concurrency.
Added Grails 2.3, the Async features of Grails aim to simplify concurrent programming within the framework and include the concept of Promises and a unified event model.*

So I guess not ?

What do I need to do if I need to use Gpars? I just follow this?
http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/gettingStarted.html

Comment: GPars is distributed with Groovy isn't it?  So you should just be able to use it

Comment: oh ok! thanks! what is the best practise though?

Comment: While at it, take a look at the free chapter on gpars from GiNA2 book. https://www.manning.com/books/groovy-in-action-second-edition#downloads